# location with php and PHP_SELF

Tags: php, nginx

How to setup a location in nginx where `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is pointing to the current file requested?

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name  xx.xx.xx.xx;

    location /test {
        root  /var/www/test;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include  /var/ini/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass  php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/test$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Here I get `File not found`

But if I change location to this it works

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/test/index.php;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `fastcgi_index` option and use `index.php` as its value. This index directive looks up filesystem for index file. So try like:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include  /var/ini/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass  php;
    fastcgi_index  index.php; #add this
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/test$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

the index sees /data/www/test/index.php and does internal redirect to /index.php,
so the request goes to `location ~ \.php$` and is passed to fastcgi.